# Client said she would email me in x weeks, but didn't, do I contact her?

Tags: freelance-websites, project

A client I made a website for last year, which was must appreciated on her part, contacted me in this October to tell me about a possible new project (an organization she is a member of needs a new website). She didn't make any promises or anything like that, she just asked what I would charge for it. I gave her my price, to which she replied with a positive tone and said she would talk with her organization's board and email me again in November.

It's December now and I haven't heard from her. I can only assume the board didn't like the idea, or they found someone else that charged less than I.

I think it would be a good idea to contact her and ask what decision the board made, and let her know I'm ready to help her in the future if a new project arises.

Is this a good idea? Is there something specific I should include when I contact her? Or is it to "pushy" to contact her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not, if you were told that you will be contacted? You are a professional and you probably reserved some of your time for this client. I would contact her telling that I am making work plans for this month (or next) and if she could update me if I shall still keep some time reserved for her.

This will be professional and also pushy in a good way. The client will feel obligated to respond so you can either keep some time for her or release it this month.

Just be professional.

Comment: I like how you **word this as a favor to her**. "Since you were so nice to tell me you'd be in touch around this time of the year, I would be happy to reserve some time for you". You're already on her good side :-)

Answer (score 0):

A closed mouth won't get fed.  You're assuming a lot, but the only way you can know for sure is to reach out to your customer.

Your chances are always better with past clients as opposed to trying to get repeat business.  Go for it!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have found to hold true - and not just in freelance work but in multiple aspects of my life - is *it never hurts to ask.*
By this I mean that you'll never know unless you reach out and inquire. It's good to know if you are charging higher than others because you can adjust your pricing. It's also good to know if your ideas were turned down and, if so, why. You can take this feedback to help with your future projects so you become a better and better freelance worker.
I don't feel like it is too soon or that you are being 'pushy'. Just word it in a way showing that you are still interested in helping your client in the future and would like to know how you can better adjust to fit their needs. It's always good to put it in a positive light by saying "What can I do to better suit your needs" rather than "What did I do wrong?"
I wish you the best of luck with this!